# How can I say in php that a variable can only be numbers or text?

Tags: php

I have a variable in PHP as in below:

```
        $currentMakeText = $advert->getMakeText();
        if ($currentMakeText == '' || $currentMakeText === null || $currentMakeText == '0') {
```

In the `if` statement I want to check if it is only text and if it is only numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for both:

```
if(ctype_alnum($currentMakeText)) { }
```

Or to check for either:

```
if(ctype_alpha($currentMakeText)) {
    //letters
} elseif(ctype_digit($currentMakeText)) {
    //digit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
if(is_string($currentMakeText) || is_numeric($currentMakeText))
```

Comment: `is_string` checks the type not the contents. `'**!&?--'` is a string

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/preg_match) with a regex of `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` like this:

```
$currentMakeText = $advert->getMakeText();

if (preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-9 ]/', $currentMakeText)) {
  // Your code here.
}
```

Note I added a space after `a-zA-Z0-9` so it can detect sentences of combinations of words that have spaces. But you could just remove that space to purely check for alpha number characters like this `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

And you could simplify it more by using the `i` option on the `preg_match` for case insensitivity:

```
$currentMakeText = $advert->getMakeText();

if (preg_match('/[a-z0-9 ]/i', $currentMakeText)) {
  // Your code here.
}
```